# find_package(Backtrace) behaves strangely

Tags: cmake, backtrace, cmake-modules

I'm looking at the documentation for the [FindBacktrace](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBacktrace.html) module, and unlike with, say, [FindThreads](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html) - I see no mention of a proper library target I can depend on, e.g. `Backtrace::Backtrace`. Is it really missing or just undocumented?

Also, when I use this module, I get:

```
//Library providing backtrace(3), empty for default set of libraries
Backtrace_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=
```

in my `CMakeCache.txt` (on a Devuan GNU/Linux machine). This is weird. I'm expecting to see `-lbacktrace` - because that's where I get `backtrace_create_state` and `backtrace_pcinfo` (which I need for using [Boost stacktrace](http://boostorg.github.io/stacktrace/index.html)).

So, what is the "default set of libraries"? `libbacktrace` is certainly not linked against by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the CMake-provided [Find Modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules) (e.g. FindBacktrace) provides an imported target, it will almost *certainly* be documented. You can inspect the [source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules) of the Find Module to be sure. In your case, for `FindBacktrace.cmake`, just search the file for the `::` syntax of the imported target it may provide. At the time of writing, `FindBacktrace.cmake` does not provide one.

Because many of the Find Modules pre-date the arrival of modern CMake, there are actually *many* of them that do not yet provide imported targets. I imagine the CMake maintainers are tackling this task as dictated by the need and popularity of each module, so writing a CMake issue for the [FindBacktrace](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindBacktrace.html) module might provoke some action.

If so inspired, you could also write your own *modified* `FindBacktrace.cmake` file, adding the requisite CMake code to define the imported target `Backtrace::Backtrace`.

---

If the system (e.g. `libc`) provides support for `backtrace(3)`, it is expected that the `Backtrace_LIBRARY` variable will be empty. The FindBacktrace module will pick up the default library if available, and populate it in `Backtrace_LIBRARIES`.

The `Backtrace_LIBRARY` cache path should only be used if your backtrace is available on your system through some other external library or package, such as on non-glibc systems. In that case, you'll populate `Backtrace_LIBRARY` manually.

Comment: Well, the thing is, it seems that some functionality is not within the system library: `backtrace_create_state`, `backtrace_pcinfo`. I'm trying to use the Boost stacktrace library with backtrace functionality, and it needs these functions. And to have them, I need to add `-lbacktrace`

Comment: @einpoklum If the functionality is not provided via the system library, you'll probably have to grab a different backtrace implementation elsewhere, install it, and then populate the `Backtrace_LIBRARY` cache entry (and potentially `Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIR`) to point CMake to this new installation instead.

Comment: It seems it's part of libgcc, so it's kind of a system library; but you still need to link against it explicitly. A bit like libdl I guess, which is part of libc.

Answer (score 1):

As @squareskittles suggests, this is just something the CMake developers should attend to.

I have filed a [bug against CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20991) on this matter and will (hopefully remember to) update this question to indicate when the module gets updated.

**Edit:** CMake developers say "merge requests are welcome".